# how to deploy and update erlang apps without releases

Tags: deployment, erlang

Using releases and relups properly to deploy and update erlang apps is difficult and sometimes not worth it.

From http://learnyousomeerlang.com/relups:

> If it is possible to upgrade your application in ways that do not
>   require relups, I would recommend doing so. It is said that divisions
>   of Ericsson that do use relups spend as much time testing them as they
>   do testing their applications themselves. They are a tool to be used
>   when working with products that can imperatively never be shut down.

I'd like to try another way. I know some people develop complex applications and do not use releases. If you are one of them, please describe your workflow.

Do you just clone the repository on the host and run `make` which runs `rebar get-deps compile` and then starts the app? Or maybe you only copy beam files? How do you reload updated modules? Do you use mochiweb's reloader? Etc.

In other words, how do you deploy and update erlang apps without releases? What are pros and cons of this way?

Answer (score 9):

Relups are complicated, but not necessary for using releases. A relup is an upgrade fora a release.  Instead of using relups, if you can afford to take some downtime, you can simply take down your running erlang release, upgrade it, and then start it again.  A relup allows you to do an upgrade without stopping a system.  As the quote you provide mentions, this is only necessary when any downtime is unacceptable.

I would personally never run any erlang code in a production environment without using releases.  Releases allow you to bundle all dependencies together. The release is a self contained application.  Without releases, I would be lost in an endless maze of custom directory structures, build processes, dependency management, and startup scripts.

There is a lot of general fuss made about the difficulty of dealing with releases, but in my experience that just isn't the case.  It is true that getting an existing working project to fit into a release can be tricky, but if you use them from the ground up with the right tools, it's simpler than rolling your own.  Rebar makes most of the tedious tasks involved simple.

A disadvantage of not using releases comes with interoperating with other erlang applications.  For example, CouchDB was not initially written to be OTP compliant.  As a result, many people who want to embed it into their erlang applications are unable to do so without looking at alternative distributions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I didn't say relups and releases are the same thing. I'd just like to know if avoiding releases could make things easier.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood your question.  Sorry.